# Grouping by row number in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let’s say you have this set of records on a database:

```
PartNumber     Qty    Group  
   A           1       1   
   B           2       1
   C           3       1
   B           4       1
   a           1       2
   B           2       2
   C           3       2
   B           4       2
```

How can we come up with this result:

```
   A       2
   B       4
   C       6
   B       8
```

That is, adding the first row of the first group with the first row of the second group, the second row of the first group with the second row of the second group, the third row of the first group with the third row of the second group and so on.

Notes:
*- I can have multiples groups
*- The groups will always have the same length (i.e the same number of rows PER GROUP)
*- The partnumbers in the group will always be the same in the same order
*- I can have multiples partnumber repeat, i.e not only B repeat but all of them PER GROUP

I know I can add a new column to the table to have something like this:

```
PartNumber    Qty    Group    idx
   A          1       1       1
   B          2       1       2
   C          3       1       3
   B          4       1       4
   a          1       2       1
   B          2       2       2
   C          3       2       3
   B          4       2       4
```

and: select partnumber, sum(qty) from table group by idx
 but that's exactly what I can't do. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @JNevill "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) "

Comment: Your table is just an unordered set of `(PartNumber, Qty, Group` values. Hence there is no first, second, etc, row per group. Is there another column governing order in your table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes, I have an Id (auto-incremental) column. Sorry not to mentioned before.

Comment: Your last 4 rows sample `idx = 1 - 1 - 3 - 4 `? is that ok?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It wasn't. Just edited. Didn't noticed. Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to create `idx` field that you mention in the OP. Then its a simple `GROUP BY` to get desired result:

```
SELECT PartNumber, SUM(Qty)
FROM (
   SELECT PartNumber, Qty, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY id) AS idx
   FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY PartNumber, idx
ORDER BY idx
```

Grouping relies on this rule stated in the OP:

> The partnumbers in the group will always be the same in the same order

I believe the above rule (no. 3) makes rule no. 2 redundant.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Let me assume there is another column that specifies the ordering (`qty` looks like such a column, but it seems to have another purpose).

With this column, we can use `row_number()` and assuming that your conditions are really true, this becomes a simple aggregation query:

```
select min(PartNumber) as PartNumber, sum(qty) as qty
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

However, I prefer this version, just to check the part numbers:

```
select (case when min(PartNumber) = max(PartNumber) then min(PartNumber)
             else 'Oops! Parts don''t match'
        end) as PartNumber, sum(qty) as qty
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok:-

```
with temptable as
(
select 
    [PartNumber], 
    [Qty], 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [group] order by [group]) [idx]
from #temp
)

select PartNumber, SUM(Qty)
from temptable
group by Partnumber, [idx]
```

See fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfa38/1